# what is var=${var:-word} bash equivalent in powershell

Tags: bash, powershell

Given this bash code:

```
HELLO =${HELLO:-hello}
```

the  variable `HELLO` takes a value from the `HELLO` environment variable if it exists. Otherwise it sets the value to be `hello`.

What is the Powershell equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.1.0, has *no* equivalent functionality to Bash's [*parameter expansion*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) feature, of which `${HELLO:-hello}` is an instance<sup>[1]</sup>.

**Note:**

- In Bash, *environment variables* and Bash's own *shell variables* share the same namespace, and environment variables are automatically exposed as shell variables.
- In PowerShell, only PowerShell's *own variables* can be referenced directly - e.g., `$myVar` - whereas referencing *environment variables* requires explicit use of the `env:` namespace - e.g., `$env:PATH`

The solutions below focus mostly on PowerShell's *own* variables, but the techniques can analogously be applied to environment variables.
Note that while environment variables are always *strings*, PowerShell variables can be of *any (.NET) type*.

---

To emulate `HELLO=${HELLO:-hello}` in PowerShell, use:

```
# To target an *environment* variable, use $env:HELLO instead.
$HELLO = if ("$HELLO") { $HELLO } else { 'hello' }
```

Note the `"..."` around `$HELLO` in the conditional, which ensures that the value is converted to a *string* before coercing it to a *Boolean*<sup>[2]</sup>: that way, both the case of `$HELLO` *not having been defined* (or explicitly containing `$null`) and the variable *containing the empty string* evaluate to `$False`, which parallels Bash's behavior.

Without the stringification with `"..."`, non-string values such as `0` or `$False` too would trigger the `else` branch.
However, if you only ever expect `$HELLO` to contain a *string* value, if any, you can omit the `"..."`.

Similarly, the above also works with *environment variables*, but since they are *always strings*, you don't strictly need the enclosing `"..."` in that case:

```
$env:HELLO = if ($env:HELLO) { $env:HELLO } else { 'hello' }
```

---

In the simple case of leaving any preexisting value of `$HELLO` alone and only assigning a default value in the in the absence of the former:

```
if (-not "$HELLO") { $HELLO = 'hello' }

# As an environment variable
if (-not $env:HELLO) { $env:HELLO = 'hello' }
```

---

To emulate `HELLO=${HELLO-hello}` - note the absence of the `:` -, use:

```
$HELLO = if ($null -eq $HELLO) { 'hello' } else { $HELLO }

# Simplified
if ($null -eq $HELLO) { $HELLO = 'hello' }
```

This covers only the case of `$HELLO` *not being defined* (and also it explicitly containing `$null`, but that isn't common).

Note that the `$null` is deliberately used as the *LHS*, which is a good habit to form in PowerShell to avoid surprises if the LHS happens to be an *array*, in which case `-eq` acts an *array filter* rather than returning a Boolean.

---

<sup>[1] While Bash's parameter expansion will likely never be implemented in PowerShell *as such*, simply because it is not a good syntactic fit for the language, providing  concise, PowerShell-idiomatic analogs to Bash's `${HELLO-hello}` and `${HELLO=hello}` *is* being discussed, as `$HELLO ?? 'hello'` and `$HELLO ?= 'hello'` - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3240).</sup>

<sup>[2] PowerShell coerces any string to a Boolean with this simple rule: if the string is *empty*, it evaluates to `$False`; if it is non-empty - whatever its contents - it evaluates to `$True`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way is :

```
$Hello = If($env:hello -eq $null){"WORLD"}else{$env:hello}
```

Or you can make a alias if you plan on using it a lot

```
function IfNull($If, $Else){
    if($If -eq $Null){
        $Else
    }else{
        $If
    }
}

Add-Alias "??" IfNull

$Hello = ?? $env:hello "World2"
```